# Have ReSharper keep 'using System;' when optimizing usings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resharper, using-directives

I was wondering if there is some option to keep ReSharper from removing just the `using System;` directive? Perhaps this is configurable somewhere?

Also, is there a way to have ReSharper sort the remaining directives just as Visual Studio 2008 does it (alphabetically, I think)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is such an option: ReSharper->Languages->C#->Namespace Imports. You can add namespaces,that should not be removed, as well as namespaces, that should always be imported.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in the options (`Resharper` > `Options` > `Languages` > `C#`), there is a `Namespace Imports` section that allows you to specify namespaces that should never be removed. You would put `System` into the prompt it gives.