# Is there a way to automatically sort the using directives alphabetically in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005

There is [this option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514113.aspx) available in Visual Studio 2008.

Is there a similar option in Visual Studio 2005? Or something else that would accomplish such a task? An add-in, maybe?

Comment: Why don't you just switch to 2008 instead of hunting for plugins?

Comment: Because that would not be the best use of my team's time and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper has a sort function. But it looks like all System usings are put on top, and then the rest alphabetically.

Also check [this question also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356010/have-resharper-keep-using-system-when-optimizing-usings) on optimizing usings with Resharper.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got Visual Assist, that's got a 'Sort Selected Lines' command that will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper can remove the unused 'using' statements. I'm not 100% sure it can also sort them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're cleaning up the files with unsorted `using` statements once (as opposed to having to deal with them on an on-going basis, perhaps because of a sloppy/uncooperative coworker?), and you are willing to use another tool for the job, there is another option.

I like using VS 2005 for its intellisense, but sometimes find the editor lacking in power compared to Emacs. I have Epsilon (an Emacs clone) which has the command `sort-region`, which takes the lines in the current selection and sorts them alphabetically. I can even type in a keyboard macro in Epsilon that:

- Finds the first using statement in a file and starts the selection there.
- Finds the last using statement in the file.
- Sorts the lines between the first and last using statement.
- Saves the file.